# Local Notification every 24 hours in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm looking for a way to fire a local notification once every 24 hours from a certain time.

For example:
I have a date picker.
I set the date picker time to 3.02pm.
The next time it's 3.02pm fire a local notification.
Repeat this over and over.

I have managed to successfully call a local notification at a time chosen by a date picker but how do I go about repeating this every 24 hours?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html Specifically the `repeatInterval` variable

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat a local notification using the **repeatInterval** property. 
To repeat a local notification every day, add this line to your code

```
myLocalNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
```

Comment: @DharmeshKheni if we want to repeat weekly then ?

Answer (score 1):

`UILocalNotification` is deprecated in iOS 10. Use `UNNotificationRequest` instead.

```
myNotificationRequest.trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60*60*24, repeats: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3**

```
myLocalNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.day
```